# How to convert a standard font to a web-font

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

Is it possible to take a standard font `.ttf` and make a web-font like Google Web Fonts, embedded into a web-page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've built [a simple webfont generator called Fontie](https://fontie.pixelsvsbytes.com/webfont-generator), which might be what you're looking for.

Fontie takes an OTF or TTF file and generates you a webfont-package, which contains everything you need (the required font-files, the CSS, etc.) to use the font on your site. It even does some extra work to ensure that your font looks good in any browser. If you want to know what it is doing in detail, you should read [my post on Pixels vs. Bytes about how to create webfonts](http://pixelsvsbytes.com/2013/11/how-to-create-perfect-web-fonts-in-3-steps/).

*PS: I'm aware that linking to my own sites won't be appreciated here, but I think my tool is a good solution to the problem, so I posted it anyway. Please leave a comment if you want me to remove this post and I'll do so.*

Comment: Looks like Fontie is no longer operational? Or has it been moved?

Comment: It was offline due to server problems, but it is back online now.

Answer (score 1):

WOFF (Web Open Font Format - see wikipedia for more details) files can be created as wrappers on TTF files and then hosted as web fonts.

First you have to be sure that you have permission to redistribute the TTF.

If it is your own font and you specifically wanted to add it to google fonts,  you can submit it at http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/. Google Web Fonts is an Open source project.

The source code should contain tools for packaging your TTF file with metadata to create the WOFF web font. There is also an excellent forum where you can find out more about what is involved:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/googlefontdirectory-discuss

The developer API is a very useful resource, search google for web fonts developer api.

The web font mechanism is not restricted to open source, I believe you can use it to distribute proprietary fonts. E.g. see the web font loader github project which allows custom/proprietary providers.